# overflow horizontal images without causing a scroll

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a design working that has images that overflow horizontally up to a certain point, but don't cause scrollbars.  Best explained by an image:

```
         +-------------------------------------------+
         |                                           | <-- the window
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                             |
| the image that is really wide                               |
|                                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
         |                                           |
         |    +--------------------------------+     |
         |    |                                |     |
         |    |    content that should cause   |     |
         |    |    a horizontal scroll         |     |
         |    |                                |     |
         |    +--------------------------------+     |
         |                                           |
         +-------------------------------------------+
```

basically, the content is 960px.  The wide image is 1800px.  I want horizontal scrollbars below 960px, but not above, and I want all the content to be centered when above 960px.

I know I've seen similar designs before.  If someone can just point me at one, that would be great, or if you happen to have the CSS for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow) for the picture.
Use [min-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/min-width) for the content.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `margin: auto` in the css file.  Or you could position the wide picture absolutely.  Then set it's left margin negatively so it is centered.

```
.widePicture{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; (this places the left edge in the center)
    margin-left: -900px; (since the pic is 1800px wide, this will center it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your 'image that is really wide' in background of a div (no margin, width 100%), use css to center your bg image.
It will not cause horizontal scroll anymore